# Modx not working anymore, File manager gone

Tags: html, css, modx, file-manager

I got the assignment to replace A current webpage with another webpage with ModX.
I asked if i could delete the files and they said yes so i did so.
But now none of my folders are showing and every page i click on is blank.
I dont know how to solve this. This is my first time with ModX
Here is are 2 screenshots that explain it better: 1. http://prntscr.com/d21mqe 2. http://prntscr.com/d21nty

I hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Reupload setup files of fresh modx installation and run setup once again.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues that might cause this error.

You could try different things:

- As it is a frech installation, reinstall it. Files might be missing.
- If you look at the source code, some files might cause a 404 error. especially the **/connectors/lang.js.php?ctx=mgr&topic=topmenu,file,resource...** You could try and edit file permissions. In most cases this is related to "*Do you run php as apache module or as fastCGI?*"
- Try and access the manager with or without www prefix in the domain name. If mod_rewrite rules work the wrong way, it might cause this empty MODX manager
- for troubleshooting in general, look at Bob Rays famous MODX articles: http://bobsguides.com/modx-troubleshooting.html